# hypothesis testing with central limit theorem

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing, central-limit-theorem

Company A claims that the average number of biscuits in a tin of BiskO shortbread
biscuits is $27$. The fair business regulators believes that the Company A’s claims
are inaccurate, and that the true average number of biscuits in a tin is less than
$27$. To prove their claim, the number of biscuits in $50$ tins of BiskO were counted
and the sample mean $\overline X$ was $25.3$ biscuits. Assume that the standard deviation of
number biscuits in a tin of BiskO is known to be $2.6$.

(a) Construct appropriate null and alternative hypotheses for this situation. Make
sure the null hypothesis is simple.

(b) Perform the test using the hypotheses you outlined above at level $\alpha = 0.05$
based on the sample data. Make note of any approximations used. What do
you conclude about Company A’s claim?

So I am a little stuck here. I was having a conversation with others about it and with our lecturer about part a and our answer is that we will use the central limit theorem.

$H_0$ is $\mu=27$ and

$H_A$ is $\mu < 27$

But when it comes to part b, I'm unsure on how to apply the central limit theorem . I can't see it anywhere in my lecture notes so any advice on how to perform this would be great.

Comment: Edited some text to improve readability. I request you to keep your language as formal as possible. Your hypotheses are correct : if you've heard of confidence intervals, this is the calculation of confidence intervals with known variance. This calculation may already have been done on this website, but you can search for it using that particular catch phrase.

Comment: One more edit to use Greek letter $\mu$ for the population mean.

Answer (score 1):

I have put the relevant numbers into the 'one-sample z test'
procedure of a recent release of Minitab software.

According to the Central Limit Theorem, we are assuming that the average number of biscuits per tin has a normal distribution
with unknown population mean $\mu$ and known standard
deviation $\sigma = 2.6,$ so that the standard error
is $\sigma/\sqrt{n}.$ [*Standard error* is the usual name for $SD(\bar X).]$

We wish to test $H_0: \mu = 27$
against the alternative $H_a: \mu < 27,$ at the 5% level of
significance $\alpha.$ You have correctly stated these (except for
using $u$ instead of Greek letter $\mu,$ which I fixed.) Now, here are some
clues for doing part (b).

Results from Minitab are shown below:

```
One-Sample Z 

Test of μ = 27 vs < 27
The assumed standard deviation = 2.6

 N    Mean  SE Mean  95% Upper Bound      Z      P
50  26.300    0.368           26.905  -1.90  0.028
```

In your text or class notes, find the formula for computing the test statistic $Z$
and do the appropriate computation to obtain the value
shown in the output above. [Some of the "Relevant" links in the margin of this page may also be helpful.]

For this one-sided test at the 5% level, the critical value is $c = -1.645.$
That is, we reject the null hypothesis because $Z \le -1.645.$
How was this critical value $c$ obtained? (Use a printed
table of the standard normal CDF, a statistical calculator,
or a statistical computer program.)

Most software programs show P-values. One rejects at
the 5% level if the P-value is less than $0.05 = 5\%.$
So, also according to that criterion, we would Reject $H_0.$

[The output labeled '95% Upper Bound' is for a one-sided
confidence interval, and is not directly relevant to your
question.]

If the null hypothesis is true then $Z$ is approximately
distributed as a standard normal random variable. The
figure below (made using R) shows the standard normal density function.
The critical value $c$ is at the vertical red dotted line.
The observed value of the z statistic is at the heavy
black line. The P-value is the area under the density
curve to the left of the heavy black line.

[image]